# Global Step for Differential Learning Rate

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34945554/how-to-set-layer-wise-learning-rate-in-tensorflow), I am trying to implement differential learning rates as follows:

```
var_list1 = [variables from first 5 layers]
var_list2 = [the rest of variables]

#Create Two Separate Optimizers
opt1 = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.00001)
opt2 = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.0001)

# Compute Gradients for eacch set of variables
grads1, variables1 = zip(*opt1.compute_gradients(loss, var_list1))
grads2, variables2 = zip(*opt2.compute_gradients(loss, var_list2))

# Apply Gradients
train_op1 = opt1.apply_gradients(zip(grads1, variables1))
train_op2 = opt2.apply_gradients(zip(grads2, variables2), global_step=global_step)
train_op = tf.group(train_op1, train_op2)
```

I am unsure if `global_step` should be included in each `apply_gradients` call or if it should only be included in 1?  My understanding is that when apply_gradients is called, `global_step` is incremented by 1 if it is supplied ([code here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py#L561)). Based on this, I believe that I should only include `global_step` in one of my `apply_gradients()` calls. Can anybody confirm that this is the correct approach?

The alternative to what I have above would be to do the following:

```
train_op1 = opt1.apply_gradients(zip(grads1, variables1), global_step=global_step)
train_op2 = opt2.apply_gradients(zip(grads2, variables2), global_step=global_step)
```

While technically each call to `apply_gradients` is a step, my understanding is that global_step should represent the number of mini-batches that have been completed so if I were to reference it in both `apply_gradients()` calls then the global step would increase twice per mini-batch. So, based onthis I believe the more accurate implementation would be the first implementation where it is called once. Would others agree this is the correct implementation? Does it matter which `apply_gradients()` the global_step is included in?

Comment: I think adding `global_step` to both should be fine as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47156113/how-to-alternate-train-ops-in-tensorflow).

Comment: In that example, they alternate between the two optimizers so the global_step would only be called once on each step.